# Making a copy of docker-desktop cluster or making a new cluster using it as template

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

Docker Desktop for Windows and macOS come with the `docker-desktop` cluster. I'm trying to figure out how to either copy it, or make a new cluster based on it as a template. I like to have clusters for each project I'm working on so that things like PVC, PV and secrets are isolated, and I can just switch between them with `kubectl config use-context project1`. I've been looking through documentation and Google search results and haven't identified how to do this, or if it is possible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a set of resources that you want to routinely deploy to new clusters, you can create a source-control repository that contains the YAML files you need.  Then when you have a new cluster you can `kubectl apply -f` your directory of bootstrap artifacts.  Using [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io), for example:

```sh
kind create cluster --name dev2
kubectl apply -f ./bootstrap/
...
kind delete cluster --name dev2
```

If you need to configure or parameterize this setup in some way, packaging it as a [Helm](https://helm.sh) chart can make sense.

This approach also means avoiding the imperative-style `kubectl create`, `kubectl run`, and `kubectl expose` type commands.  Create the YAML files you need, check them in, and use `kubectl apply` to install them.

It can be a little tricky to usefully export a cluster, and this isn't something that's commonly done.  For example, if you have a Pod, was it created by a Deployment or directly through a YAML file?  Was that PersistentVolume hand-created, or did a provisioner create it, and are its settings specific to a particular Kubernetes environment?  Working from a reproducible source-controlled tree avoids these issues.